# Cisco Router ( 2611XM ) and ISP Internet connection

Tags: cisco, router

I recently acquired a Cisco 2611XM that looks like this:

[image]

Now the one I have has only 1 FastEthernet port (Was expecting 2) but I was wondering I purchase a WIC1T - CSU/DSU module for it could I use that to accept the Internet IP address from my ISP? (if i configure it for DHCP etc)?

[image]

IF not, please advise on how I can allow something like that to occur with my 2611XM router. Thank you for your time.

I do have a CCNA with Cisco, but this seems to be a bit out of my knowledge base of what I've done so far.

Comment: Do you have a T1 to connect to the WIC1T? It not, what purpose would it serve? What form does your connection to your ISP take?

Comment: I have ethernet cable that comes in from the Outside FiOS installation. So a current Netgear N750 home router is capable of accepting that connection (via ethernet). I want to replace the N750 with my router so I can configure a VPN and other things as a lab with another partner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two fast Ethernet ports on a Cisco 2611XM and two are shown in your picture. The two ports with the yellow labels under them are both FE ports. A T1 WIC won't do you any good unless you have a T1 to connect to it.

Comment: So the 2611XM is 100% usually with a 2 ports? If it is not two ports that means its probably a 2600 series not XM ... Is that correct? --- I received one without two fast Ethernet ports.

Comment: @Bain: That is my understanding. A 2610XM has 1 FE port. A 2610 has 1 10MBps Ethernet port. See table 1-1 of [this Cisco guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/2600/hardware/installation/guide/2600ch1.html#wp1025557).

Comment: So the router I purchased says its 2611 XM but there is a sticker running through the whole where a 2611XM router would have that 2nd ethernet port. I believe my router is a fraudulent 2611XM  :(

Comment: @Bain: Wow, can you put up a picture? What does the sticker say or look like? (There's [a guide](http://info.publicintelligence.net/FakeCiscoRouters.pdf) to spotting counterfeit routers from US-CERT. Usually the differences are subtle though.)

Comment: So did a bit more research, thank you David S. For all your information and knowledge. I looked at the model being sold and it was being sold as a 2611XM but I was sent a 2610XM ... Big difference as there is only 1 FA port on the xx10XM version. Will be talking with seller for sure. Thank you so much. I don't think its fraudulent though, I cannot turn it on and check the hardware as I need to get a console cable adapter.

Comment: If you have a managed switch, you can use VLANs. Connect the 2610XM to the switch. On the router configure one virtual interface in VLAN 1 and one in VLAN 2. On the switch, you can put the physical interfaces for your LAN in VLAN 1 and the one to your ISP in VLAN 2. Set the switch interface that connects to the router as tagged and in both VLANs.

Comment: Got it, so I'm able to still use a 2610XM but I'd need a switch to configure some VLANs to allow it to work with one FA port. I wanted to do one port for internal, and one for external. I believe i'd have to configure alot of extra things once I start setting up a VPN and including other devices in. Especially with NAT etc (im still learning all of this ). Thank you David :)

Comment: Yep, you got it. You're welcome.

Comment: I'm curious, once I do attain the 2611XM or an ISR router like a 2800 series, how would that be done to configure to get IP address from ISP? Do i just set up DHCP like i mentioned? --Sorry to drag on discussion--

Comment: You enable DHCP on the interface to the ISP using the [ip address dhcp](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_3t/12_3t8/feature/guide/gtdhcpcf.html#wp1067613) interface configuration command.

Answer (score 0):

I won't touch on the ports as this is well covered by David Schwartz, but I did want to touch on the other aspect of using this device for your ISP router that hasn't been addressed, which is the router performance.

The 2611XM is a very old model of router that were primarily designed at the time as "branch routers" often utilizing Frame Relay (56k to T1 speeds).  While it does have Fast Ethernet ports, it has no where near the performance to come close to that throughput.  I have come across a number of situation where people buy these devices expecting them to be able to route 100Mbps of traffic.

According to this [Cisco router performance document](http://www.cisco.com/web/partners/downloads/765/tools/quickreference/routerperformance.pdf), if all the traffic takes full advantage of hardware forwarding, then you can expect just over 10Mbps of throughput.  If you have FiOS, odds are you need a device with more forwarding capability as this won't suffice.